# Render precompressed data with Zlib and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zlib

Assuming that for storage efficiency you have compressed your infrequently accessed database data using Zlib, and someone using a browser requests some of this data. How would one go about serving this data?

Here's an unrealistic but straightforward example of what I want:

```
require "zlib"

class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    compressed_data = Zlib::Deflate.deflate("Some precompressed database data.")
    render :text => compressed_data
  end
end
```

This serves the compressed data to the client's browser, but does not decompress it for proper viewing. Is there a way to make this work so that the client receives this data in an uncompressed (inflated) state. The point is that I don't want to inflate in the controller, just to deflate again using `Rack::Deflater`. I want to avoid unnecessary cpu usage / time consumption, while lowering storage and bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this possible you'll first of all need to set the `Content-Encoding` header to `gzip`. And instead of using `Zlib::Deflate.deflate` you'll want to create a new `StringIO` buffer object, pass it in to a `Zlib::GzipWriter` object, and through it write to the `StringIO` buffer object. When done, close the `Zlib::GzipWriter` object. Finally, render out the buffer's string.

For example:

```
require "zlib"
require "stringio"

class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    response.headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip"

    buffer = StringIO.new

    gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(buffer, Zlib::DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Zlib::DEFAULT_STRATEGY)
    gz.write("Some precompressed database data.")
    gz.close

    render :text => buffer.string
  end
end
```

Alternatively, `ActiveSupport::Gzip` apparently has a built-in class method which allows you to accomplish the same with less code.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    response.headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip"

    string = ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress("Some precompressed database data.")

    render :text => string
  end
end
```

The latter example will work in Rails environments, or other environments that include the `ActiveSupport` framework, and is basically a wrapper for the former example, which you can use if you don't have access to `ActiveSupport::Gzip`.